# Address book change notification in Swift iOS 8+

Tags: swift

I have tried the code below but no luck.

```
if let addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil) {

    let ref = addressBook
    let callback: @convention(c) (addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef!, info: CFDictionaryRef!, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void = {
        (addressBookRef, info, context) in

        print("Address book editr ")
    }

    let addressBookChangeCallback = unsafeBitCast(callback, ABExternalChangeCallback.self)
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(ref, addressBookChangeCallback, nil)
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I basically want a trigger of insert/update/delete of contact in the address book

Comment: You need to provide more code and elaborate more on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add NSNotifications to find any Address Book changes. To add a NSNotification you should use :-

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "addressBookDidChange:", name: CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

And for remove the NSNotification :-

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

And finally add a function when addressBook changes :-

```
@objc func addressBookDidChange(notification: NSNotification){ 
     //Something You want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest api in swift is:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self, selector: #selector(addressBookDidChange), name: .CNContactStoreDidChange, object: nil)
```